# json.Unmarshal not decoding into inner interface{} correctly

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm developing a Telegram Bot API wrapper for Golang (I know there are already some but I'm doing this for learning). I have a Response struct:

```
type Response struct {
  Ok bool `json:"ok"`
  ErrorCode int64 `json:"error_code"`
  Description string `json:"description"`
  Result interface{} `json:"result"`
}
```

I can't know the actual type of `Result`: a lot can be returned by Telegram servers; I made a struct for each one, but I don't know which one will be in `Result`.
When `Unmarshal`ing a JSON from an HTTP response into the `Response` struct, everything is loaded correctly, except `Result`.

In a function where I am sure Result will be an `User` (for example), I'm doing `user := resp.Result.(*User)`, but I get the following error *at runtime*:
`panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not *tgbot.User`. So, `Result` is a `map[string]interface{}`. How can I transform it into a `*User`?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it a `json.RawMessage` and unmarshal it in a second step, when you're sure what type it is.

Take a look at the examples at https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage.